# How does the chassis ground on an automobile protect against lightning

Tags: electricity, lightning

How does the chassis neutralize the excess of electrons from a lightning strike?

Comment: Read .. what is a Faraday Cage

Comment: It doesn't, it just provides an easier path for electrons to flow to ground.

Comment: Tests have shown safe results with an occupant inside a car exposed to a 1 million volt discharge but there may be exceptional situations.

Answer (score 2):

Tests** have shown safe results with an occupant inside a car exposed to a 1 million volt discharge but there will be exceptional situations.  (e.g. open sunroof and with roof antenna.)

Those tests**, which you may search on [Youtube](https://youtu.be/ve6XGKZxYxA?t=216), were even performed on a dry car. A wet car makes it easier for the >1kV/m E field stress as water is 80x stronger as a capacitor to conduct the charge to ground.  It is minute contaminants in the medium that cause the arc to bifurcate and change direction slightly or "fork" in the general direction of opposite polarity.

Answer (score 1):

> How does the chassis ground on an automobile protect against lightning and how does the chassis neutralize the excess of electrons from a lightning strike?

Specifically what the chassis is doing is providing a low impedance path for current to travel around you rather than through you.  Because the chassis is a cage arrangement of metal fully surrounding the passengers, it qualifies as a Faraday Cage, which is a device generally used to protect people or areas from electricity and or electromagnetic radiation.  Because the chassis is also insulated from ground by the rubber of the tires and air beneath the car, it could also be considered to be protecting you, not only by being a better path for current than you, but also by being a potentially less good path than other nearby objects which might be taller or overall better conductors, like posts, wet trees, buildings, towers, lightning rods, larger vehicles.

Note that during a lightning strike, the electricity is not the only danger.  There is also heat, fire, flash, flashburn, and potential explosion to consider, so being in a car when it is hit by lightning could still really suck and or be destructive or lethal.

Comment: The windows prevent the car's "fully surrounding" the humans.

Comment: @analogsystemsrf This is why it is referred to as a Faraday Cage rather than a Faraday Box.  A Faraday Cage meant to block EMP or EM interference would likely actually have several layers of varying size meshes to effectively block different frequency waves.  A car happens to be a Faraday Cage, one of the purposes of which is to divert current around the object contained, but if it were designed primarily as a Faraday Cage and secondarily as transportation it would be a very different looking beast.

Comment: I'm looking for a better way to phrase that though.  "fully surrounding with holes not larger than will pass the largest permitted wavelength" seems similarly lacking.  No part of the objects protected may pass the boundaries of the cage, but the cage need not be solid.

Comment: @KH you did not ask how to write about it, you asked how does it work...

Comment: @SolarMike I think you mean OP asked how it works.  With my second comment I'm acknowledging that I could probably have phrased better than "fully surrounding" which is only accurate combined with the assumption that a "continuous" cage can be composed both of conductive matter and the less conductive voids between.  Is this what you mean?

Comment: @KH ah, sorry, too early :) But there are cases of tractors that have hit power lines and when the driver got out they touched cab and ground st the same time and bzzt... We had one and told him to jump, luckily he did...

Comment: Oh very yes, there is a massive difference between power line danger and lightning danger.  I've luckily never been around when that happened.  It doesn't hurt to know about step voltages for energised earth in a downed line situation too.  Try to land on 1 foot or if you have to land on 2 feet keep them close together and try to hit the ground at the same time.

Comment: The resistance of the tires of the car is pretty much irrelevant.  The lightning bolt has just passed through thousands of feet of air.  That little bit of rubber just doesn't matter.

Comment: @JRE Distribution of initial resistances will determine initial path of the bolt.  I only meant to point out that it doesn't hurt that the car is not initially firmly grounded.  This would also not hold true in situations involving water, saltwater or dust.  If you were in a normal rubber tired car and near to an identical car that was firmly grounded, lightning would almost certainly strike through the other car.  Better yet if rather than another car or a tree we have a line of poles beside the road, often with a grounded wire strung across their highest points.